# Running GeoPackage with QGIS Server

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, geopackage, qgis-server, nginx

I'm trying to run GeoPackage on QGIS Server and query the information. I created a file through GeoPackage's QGIS Desktop.

To do the queries I used the following tutorial:

https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/getting_started.html#installation-on-debian-based-systems

I am trying to use Nginx and did not understand exactly where in the configuration file I am adding the next part?

[image]

Also, how do I properly link GeoPackage to a Server?